# Java - Add a new entry pair to Properties file in Runtime

Tags: java, io, runtime

I want to add a new NewKey-NewValue pair to my config properties file in runtime. I tried :

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(fileinpustream ...);
...
p.setProperty("NewKey","NewValue");
p.store(outputstream, "comment");
```

But i always get a NullPointerException on the setProperty line. 
Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: can u please post the complete code.? cant figr out anthing from this

Comment: I think you've over-trimmed your code, the `p.setProperty` line is fine (the others being pseudo-code, it makes it hard to spot an error).

Comment: Seems the problem is hidden by "..." =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your "NewValue" isn't **null**

This is from Hashtable, parent of java.util.Properties

...

```
public synchronized V put(K key, V value) {
// Make sure the value is not null
if (value == null) {
    throw new NullPointerException();
}
```

...

Comment: I had another mistake when setting the 'value', from another Method. Everything works fine now!!